# Properties проблема с символом ":"

Tags: java, properties

`Properties` проблема с символом `":"`. Есть файл `ini`, его редактирует человек, закрывает, сохраняет.

Пример ini:

```
connects=streamServer://null
module.streamServer://null.run=2
```

Дальше человек запускает программу, программа должна прочесть этот файл извлечь из него `connects`, по нему построить строчку(`module.ЗНАЧЕНИЕ ИЗ CONNECTS.commands`) и получить с помощью этой строчки значение из ini файла, с плюсовать это значение +1 и записать 3 в ini. Все вроде бы нормально, но только место читабельного вида приходится делать вот так `module.streamServer\://null.commands` а при сохранении `connects=streamServer://null`=>`connects=streamServer\://null` как научить Properties обращатся с символом `":"`, или предложите подобие `Properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Двоеточие является таким же законным разделителем ключа и значения как и знак `=` о чем развернуто написано в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load(java.io.Reader)). Кто раньше встретился в строке - тот и разделил.

Так что, если вы хотите использовать `.propeties`-файлы стандартными средствами, придется либо отказаться от двоеточий в ключах, либо экранировать их обратным слэшом.

Альтернативный вариант - написать свой класс, который будет вручную считывать файл, построчно делать `String.split("=")`, перекладывать две половинки в `Map`, а когда придет время - писать содержимое `Map`-а обратно в файл, склеивая ключ со значением символом `=`.

Comment: Думаю это единственный вариант

Answer (score 3):

А вы ничему не учите.Класс Properties сделает все за Вас. Как пример запустите код ниже

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put("asd", "one:targer");
    FileWriter w = new FileWriter(new File("config.ini"));
    p.store(w, "blabla");
    FileReader reader = new FileReader(new File("config.ini"));
    p.load(reader);
    System.out.println(p.get("asd"));
```

После выполнения данного кода Вы получите файл config.ini содержащий на борту

```
#blabla
#Sun Mar 20 23:44:00 EET 2016 
asd=one/:targer
```

далее вычитывание из это файла вернет Вам строку:

```
one:targer
```

и не стоит обязывать пользователя добавлять / в файл config т.к и с его отсутствием Класс Properties справиться.[Причина](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-) в том что при чтении из файла ключом считается часть строки до первого не экранированного символа / или : остальная часть  - значение.

Ну на последок упомяну о библиотеке [ini4j](http://ini4j.sourceforge.net/index.html) которая по сути разработана для более тесного общения с файлами .ini.Удачи